# Can't add column in dataGridView

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I try to add column into dataGridView. But when I click add button, Visual Studio become "Not Responding"

I don't know why, and how to fix it. Can you help me to solve this ? Thank alot

[Can't adding column into dataGridView image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fIh6k.png)

Comment: Does this happen with only one particular solution or does this always happen when you try to create a new solution? If Visual Studio is crashing or “Not Responding” … then I suggest you uninstall and then re-install Visual Studio.

Comment: Dear John, only this particular solution has a problem
I still can create and add columns in another project or in the user control. 
I think this happening with my project, not at Visual Studio